Interpreting a SAS code on freq procedure
I have come across following SAS code
proc freq data mydata;
tables _char_;
run;

I fail to understand what  char implies here. Is it some reserve word for SAS? What does it do? What are similar things exist in SAS?

It is SAS variable list short for all character variables in data set referenced in DATA= proc statement option.
_CHAR_ aka _CHARACTER_ 

SAS Variable Lists
